# CSS Media Queries don't work on mobile devices

Tags: android, css, ios, mobile, media-queries

***The media queries were working correctly. Had an issue with the linking of my stylesheet. Thanks a lot for your answers! Won't delete this questions to keep the knowledge to the community***

I'm struggling with my media queries. If I resize my browser window they work properly, but when I emulate mobile devices (`IOS` and `Android`) with the Google Chrome device emulator, they won't work.

```
@media (max-width: 650px)
```

Adding only a screen or a min-width doesn't change anything. The viewport tag is set.

Is there anything I need to know? **Thanks a lot!**

Comment: @jeprubio Thanks a lot, but the tag is set. Will add this to my question. :)

Comment: You could add some of this rules to the question or create a codepen to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 3):

You should set the meta viewport tag in the html header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And you could add !important to the media query rules to check if other rules are overriding them

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the tag is set. Will add this to my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

Also, set a meta viewport tag in your HTML head component

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the tag is set. Will add this to my question. :)